# get current user in Javascript/jQuery Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How I can get the current user in JS/Jquery? In the blade we can do like

`{{Auth::user()}}` But it wont work in the .js file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per looking at the standard and the way most javascript templates engine work, I would prefer to do something like this:

1. Install `laracasts/utilities` by using `composer require laracasts/utilities`
2. In the controller method, from where you are returning view, I would make it look like this:

   ```
   public function returnUser(){
       $user = Auth::user();
       Javascript::put([ 'user.name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email ]);
       return view('my.user.js');
   }
   ```
3. In the blade file, I would simply do,

   ```
   <script>alert("Hi " + user.name + ". Your email is " + user.email)</script>
   ```

And yeah, I would even prefer the way, @Robbin said. And yeah just one more edit to his answer, in laravel 5.1, `Auth::user()` should not be used. It should be used as `auth()->user() //->name or ->email or ->anything`.

Comment: True! Adding that instead.

Comment: `Javascript::put([])` will put these values in each js file?

Comment: Javascript::put([]) will put the variables in the window scope so you can access them on that specific route. If you want the variable accessable on all routes you have to put the javascript::put([]) in forexample a constructor on a basecontroller

Comment: `window.user = {!! auth()->user() !!}`

Answer (score 6):

You have to build an API and get it with AJAX. You cannot use blade in javascript files.

Or, in the `<head>` of your template, you place.

```
<script>
  var user = {!! json_encode((array)auth()->user()) !!};
</script>
<!-- include your js file  here-->
```

And use the user var in your js file.

EDIT:

As per Mark's comment this is indeed cleaner:

```
<script>
  var user = {!! auth()->user()->toJson() !!};
</script>
<!-- include your js file  here-->
```

Comment: Eloquent models have a toJson() method. Would it not be clearer to use that?

Comment: what will user contain? how would I access name of user in js? like user-name?

Comment: user.name, user.email etc

Comment: @Adamnick just try to put user variable in the console of Google chrome. try to do this: `console.log(user);`

Answer (score 0):

simply =>

1. add any **input** or any **tag** to inject auth-user inside it, in my case:

   < meta name="auth-check" content="{{ (Auth::check()) ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
2. in **JS** file u can get a value from your tag using **jquery**!

var authcheck = $('meta[name="auth-check"]').attr('content');

***I hope my idea is useful, my best wishes***

Comment: You cannot ever believe that variable tho - because someone else can easily change it in element inspector.